# Linear differential equations and IVP

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Hey I'm currently stuck on this question. I don't think its in the form of an integrating factor, but I'm also not sure if its separable?

$$\frac {dy}{dx}=-3y+2e^{-x}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general form for an equation solvable by integrating factor is
$$\frac{dy}{dx}+P(x)y=Q(x).$$

In your case I see
$$\frac{dy}{dx}+3y=2e^{-x}.$$

Comment: But the second part for P(x)y don't we need an x term? Like, I'm not sure how to find the integrating factor here.

Comment: How about $P(x)=3x^0$. There is your $x$ term. ;). Not to be a smarty pants, just think of $P(x)$ as being $P(x)=3$.

Comment: Oh i see that now! Could you tell me if I'm correct, where the integrating factor is:

$$e^{3x+c}$$ or simplified to be $$e^{3x}$$

Comment: If your have $\mu(x)=e^{\int 3\, dx }$ then you are correct.

Comment: yeah, thanks a lot!

Comment: My pleasure, and best of fortune with your studies.

Comment: user176330  this kind of equations is easily solved by using the superposition principle, i always found the integration factor method a bit too specific. if you are interested in a more general/intuitive way of solving DE, comment below,  btw +1 for @Perry

Comment: Sure id like to know more about this method